# Array.prototype.findIndex() doesn't return the index of the object

Tags: node.js

I am implementing a server program using nodejs. There i have written a method to retrieve the index of an object in an array (planning to remove the particular object from the array). Below is the implementation of the method

```
async function findConsecutiveSessions(_session){
    if (_session.ConsecutiveSessionID !== ""){

        consecutiveSession = await getConsecutiveSession(_session.ConsecutiveSessionID);
        
        let index = await sessions.findIndex(obj => obj._id === consecutiveSession._id)
        console.log(index)
    }
}

async function getConsecutiveSession(_consecutiveSessionId){

    let session;

    session = await Sessions.findOne({_id: _consecutiveSessionId});

    return session;
}
```

**Scenario :-**

I have declared an array called `sessions` which contains all the session objects. A session object may contain an id of another session object as `ConsecutiveSessionID`. By using `getConsecutiveSession(_session.ConsecutiveSessionID)` I can find the relavent consecutive session of a particular session if there is one.

**What I want :-**

The returned session object is already in `sessions` array. Therefore, I want to remove the returned session from the `sessions` array. (I will use the sessions.splice() method once I could find the index properly).

**Current Output :-**

I used console.log() to print the index values. But it prints -1 for all the passed _session values. I cross checked with the database (MongoDB) to check whether the ids are correct and there were no issue. Below is a sample documents in the db.

```
_id : 5f4698bde7bb344004500f32
LecName : Array
UnAvailableTime : Array
ConsecutiveSessionID : "5f63463c38f68521ae241844"
Rooms : Array
SubName : "SEPQM"
SubCode : "SE3010"
Tag : "Lecture"
GroupOrSubGroupName : "Y1.S1.SE.10"
NoOfStudents : 120
Duration : 2
__v : 0

_id : 5f63463c38f68521ae241844
LecName : Array
times : Array
ConsecutiveSessionID : "5f4698bde7bb344004500f32"
Rooms : Array
SubName : "SEPQM"
SubCode : "SE3010"
Tag : "Tutorial"
GroupOrSubGroupName : "Y1.S1.SE.10.1"
NoOfStudents : 120
Duration : 1
__v : 0
```

There are some other documents without `ConsecutiveSessionId`. I just provided matching sessions to get an idea. What could be the possible error? Can some one please help me? Thanks!

Comment: Can't tell for sure because I don't see contents of the `sessions` but my guess is that this is happening due to type mismatch. MongoDB ids are not strings even if they look like that. If you are comparing MongoDB ID with a string, it will always fail.

Comment: Oh I did not aware of that. And I am comparing with the mongoDB id. So do I have to convert mongoDB ID to string before compare? @MatusDubrava

Comment: Yes, you need to convert them to strings.